# Vue router.push: How to check if component or content is loaded?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nodes, vue-router, vuetify.js

As per all my post, I just want to make it known that I am still new to Laravel + VueJS, so please be as detailed as possible when posting your answers or comments. Thanks.

I am using Vue's router.push() to retrieve pages. Example code as follows:

```
editHandler(id) {
    let self = this
    self.$router.push({ name: 'inventory/Suppliers/Edit', params: { id } 
    })
}
```

I planned to add a loading overlay on the onClick event but I need help to check when the component/content has been loaded so that I can hide the loading overlay. Anyone can help me how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
next()
})

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample code based on what I posted above? Thanks.

Comment: Do you retrieve any data when you are opening that component based on that id?

Comment: Since you are new and still don't understand the concept of Vue/SPA.  It's not a server-side load so it's pretty instantaneous.  There is no need for loading overlay unless you're doing some ajax - per @NielsLucas question ref.

Comment: In the example code above, the method push to a controller that does a database query and fetch data into the page. All I wanted to do was to be able to check if the result have been returned and hide the overlay. Sorry if I misunderstood what you are trying to tell me.

As per Niels question, in the code example, it does use the ID to retrieve the data but there are instances where I may not use any ID, ie. listing all suppliers. Hope that is clear. Thanks.

Comment: @AllieSyadiqin when you do have an id, You use axios or something else to make an APi call? If so, you can do something like this. Sorry for my lazyness i just made a screenshost: 1: https://gyazo.com/ba5f6e1d437459b2b98363e0c30b481a
2: https://gyazo.com/c9d30f08db3d27d89b622e5cbde235b0

Comment: just to be sure,  is "inventory/Suppliers/Edit" a component reference ?